# Simpe Objects & Classes issue

Tags: java

I am practicing Objects & Constructors and ended up making this code, however when I run it, the String colorGenerated comes up as null, thus appearing as "The Color Generated was: null". I have tried to change and fix it but failed to do so. Thank you for reading.

```
public class Color{
    int colorValue;
    String colorGenerated1;

    public Color(String colorGenerated){
        System.out.println("The Color Generated was: " + colorGenerated);
    }

    public void randomizeColor(){
        Random randomColor= new Random();
        colorValue = randomColor.nextInt(3);
    }

    public int getColor(){

        if(colorValue == 1){
            colorGenerated1 = "Red";
        } else if(colorValue == 2){
            colorGenerated1 = "Blue";
        } else if(colorValue == 3){
            colorGenerated1 = "Yellow";
        }

        return colorValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Color color = new Color("colorGenerated");
        color.randomizeColor();
        color.getColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: That behavior is not possible given the code you have posted.  Are you sure you are executing the same code?

Comment: The output you say you are getting is confusing because you only print the value passed to the constructor. The only way you would get `"The Color Generated was: null"` as the output would be if you did `new Color(null)`. The code you posted here will instead always output `"The Color Generated was: colorGenerated"`. On the other hand...what Elliott hints at is also true, that `nextInt(3)` will return `0`, `1` or `2`, so your `getColor` logic seems off by 1.

Comment: Yes yes now I see, for to me to get the range of 3 I would have to use nextInt(4) returning 0,1,2, & 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the color generated before you set it with randomize color. And you should only get your `Random` once (instead of once per method invocation). I would do something like

```
public class Color {
    private static Random random = new Random();
    int colorValue = random.nextInt(3) + 1; // nextInt excludes 3 and includes 0

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (colorValue == 1) {
            return "Red";
        } else if (colorValue == 2) {
            return "Blue";
        } else if (colorValue == 3) {
            return "Yellow";
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color color = new Color();
        System.out.println("The Color Generated was: " + color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so much easier to understand. Really appreciate the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

First you make an instance of the class Color. Actually you run the constructor. The parameter is a string. That is showing up.
After that you initialize colorgenerated. You must after color.getColor()  show the colorgenerated, Because then it's actually initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Please have [a read](http://www.javatpoint.com/constructor) . Your code is working fine as expected .

- You added print statement in your constructor & you initializing an object very first .
- Then you added code for randomize the color & there is no method for print the color .
- So , you will get only null when you call the constructor .

Comment: Than you, I simply ignored the fact that I did not know what null stands for but now I know thanks to you.